# Create map with courses and the number of his members

Tags: java

Not sure how to ask my Question properly: 
I want to create a map which should list the name of the course and his members. For example: {mathe = 4 , deutsch=2}. Is there an easy way to do this? Maybe with the help of a filter?

So far I created this code, which don´t work:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> distribution = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(Course c : courses)
{
    int k =0;
    for (Entry<Integer, Student> entry : students.entrySet()) {
      for (Course cdeep : entry.getValue().getCourses()) {
        if(cdeep.getName()==c.getName())
        {
        k++;
        }
      }
    }
  distribution.put(c.toString(), k);
}
```

In my example I have this list of students:

```
System.out.println(students.toString());
//{1=Student [matrikel=1, lastName= bruns, firstName= david, courses=[ mathe,  deutsch]], 2=Student [matrikel=2, lastName= schwade, firstName= lukas, courses=[ dumm,  mathe]], 3=Student [matrikel=3, lastName= Ebert, firstName= Niklas, courses=[ viertversuch,  durchgefallen]]}
```

In the first run Course c is "mathe" and Entry entry is the first student.
Now I check if he´s a member of the course "mathe" with:

```
for (Course cdeep : entry.getValue().getCourses()) {
                            if(cdeep.getName()==c.getName())
                            {
                                k++;
                            }
                        }
```

If it´s true the counter k increases by one.
At the end of the run k = 1, because the first student is a member of the course. Now we look at the second student. He should be a member of the course "dumm" and "mathe". So after the check, k should be increased by one. But when I check this, the if statement returns false:

```
if(cdeep.getName()==c.getName()) 
// returns: false. cdeep.getName() = "mathe" and c.getName() = "mathe"
```

In the Debug I only noticed there´s a different in the ID of the String, but content of them are still the same (="mathe").

Comment: why are you comparing using == as it will just compare objects not their values. Use equals. you must be aware about SCP and String immutability as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `equals()` on strings, not `==`

```
if(cdeep.getName().equals(c.getName()))
```

Comment: Perfect! It works, thanks! But is this the easiest way for my task?

Comment: @DavidBruns Your algorithm is perfectly sensible, if that is your question.

Comment: Yes, thought there might be a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals() method instead of `==` as it's compare reference instead of value. In your case reference is differ so it does not equal.

```
if(cdeep.getName()!=null && cdeep.getName().equals(c.getName()))
```

Do `null` check before using equals for name.